# Force height on div displaying only background-color

Tags: html, blazor, height

I am using a div to display a colour - so the actual "content" of the div is the background colour, the colour is the cell's data.

I have tried setting height to 100% or to a given px, ditto for min-height, float: left, display (block and table) but all I ever get is a block of colour say 50px high and not the 600px (or so) that I want.  Tried a html table too, same result.

The display is a text box the width of the screen, 100px high.  Underneath that I have three "columns": a grid (70% width) and two divs of 15% each (=100%) and all have the same height (tried 100% and explicit px against one or both of height and min-height).

**How do I force the div to be the height I want it to be and not the height of the content?**

This is a Blazor app btw, so the HTML below is getting embedded into a parent container (the @ is the Blazor way of interacting with C#). I have stripped this back to the raw problem with the CSS in-line.

````html
    <div style="float:left; width: 100%; height: @LayoutRootHeight; left: 0; overflow:hidden;">
        <div style="width: 100%; height: 100px;">
            <TextArea Style="height:100px; width:100%"></TextArea>
        </div>
        <div style="width:70%; height:calc(@LayoutRootHeight - 100px); float: left;">
            <Grid Style="width:100%;">
                <Columns>
                    <Column Width="70"></Column>
                    <Column Width="70"></Column>
                </Columns>
            </Grid>
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 15%; height:calc(@LayoutRootHeight - 100px);); background-color: @cdf_Colour1">
            <br />
        </div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 15%; height:calc(@LayoutRootHeight - 100px); background-color: @cdf_Colour2">
            <br />
        </div>

    </div>```
````

Answer (score 0):

I'd never have figured this one out but the answer was here:

https://matthewjamestaylor.com/equal-height-columns

```html
<div style="float:left; width:100%; overflow:hidden; position:relative; background:@cdf_Colour2;">
  <div style="float:left; width:100%; position:relative; right:15%; background:@cdf_Colour1;">
    <div style="float:left; width:100%; position:relative; right:15%;">
      <div style="float: left; width:70%; position:relative; left:30%; height:calc(@LayoutRootHeight - 100px);">
        <Grid Style="font-size:smaller; width:100%;">
          <Columns>
            <Column Width="70"></Column>
            <Column Width="70"></Column>
          </Columns>
        </Grid>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```